# Use PHP constants in Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm new to web and facing issue while using PHP file's constants inside javascript Ajax call.

My PHP code in **constants.php** file is as:

```
<?php

$color = 'green';
define ('BASE_URL', 'https://example.com?');
define ('APP_KEY', 'abcde');
define ('USER_KEY', '12345');
?>
```

My Ajax call in another **login.php** file is as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#loginPopup").on('click',function(){

    var x = document.forms["login"]["emailId"].value;
    var pwd = document.forms["login"]["pwd"].value;

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'BaseURL?appkey=abcde&userkey=12345&email='+ x +'&password=' + pwd,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',

    success: function (response) {
        showAlert(response);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
});
});
</script>
```

I want to move constants i.e. Base URL, Keys etc to constants file. So i've created constants.php. But now, i don't know how to use that inside ajax call. Please help. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Change This
url: ' <?php echo BaseURL ?>?appkey=abcde&userkey=12345&email='+ x +'&password=' + pwd,

Also needs to include constant file in login.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so, assuming the two files are in the same dir:

```
<?php
require_once('constants.php');
?>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#loginPopup").on('click',function(){

    var x = document.forms["login"]["emailId"].value;
    var pwd = document.forms["login"]["pwd"].value;

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '<?php echo BASE_URL  ?>?appkey=<?php echo APP_KEY  ?>&userkey=<?php echo USER_KEY  ?>&email='+ x +'&password=' + pwd,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',

    success: function (response) {
        showAlert(response);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
});
});
</script>
```